# access to parent HTML document in an included js file

Tags: javascript, html, include, document, parent

in HTML file include an external js file and in js file i used this method:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML='something';
```

but it dosnt work

Comment: Make certain that the id you are trying to select exists.

Comment: window.parent.document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML='something';
do not affect anything

Comment: @scrappedcola ID is exists and it is ok !

Comment: What is the type of HTML element that you are trying to change the innerHTML on? window.parent doesn't really need to be used in this case (though generally it will just refer to the current window so it doesn't really hurt anything most of the time)

Comment: also what is the context of the above code being called? Is it a click event or window load? If it is window load you need to make certain the JS is loaded after the element is unless you are using window.onload() handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are including the `window.parent` part because you want to refer to the parent of the JS file?  That's not how it works - the JS runs in the context of the HTML that includes it, so all you need is:

```
document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML='something';
```

(Forgive me if I've misinterpreted your question!)